# What is the probability that all 4 cards drawn are A,J,Q,K or heart?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose 4 cards are chosen at random from a deck of 52. What is the probability that all four cards are A,J,Q,K or heart?

So what I did is decide each of the 4 card types has 4 cards and the hearts have 13 cards but 4 of these cards can overlap because of the suits. So by using inclusion exclusion I took (4 x 4) + 13 - 4 = 25 .

My final answer is: 
P(E) = ${C(25, 4)}/{C(52, 4)}$
Is this correct?

Thank you for help in confirming.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thank you for confirming! Just seemed too simple. What is the best way to close out this question when my answer is correct?

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Alternatively:
$$P=\frac{25}{52}\cdot \frac{24}{51}\cdot \frac{23}{50}\cdot \frac{22}{49}.$$
which conforms with your answer.